# Running Android WebDriver Test on SauceLabs

Tags: java, selenium, appium, saucelabs, remotewebdriver

I'm trying to run the android emulator with webdriver on saucelabs to test some web pages. This is what I am using for my capabilities:

```
        Capabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.android()
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.2");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Android Emulator");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceType", "phone");
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Android")
```

However this gives me an error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Sauce could not start your job. For more information on what happened, please visit (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 21.74 seconds
```

All the tutorials I'm finding and answers include capabilities that install an apk, that's not something that I need.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation on https://support.saucelabs.com/entries/51370580-Android-Desired-Capabilities you don't need the apk capability, but you need to include the "browserName" one.

So you should add:

```
capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "browser");
```

This might also need to be:

```
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "browser");
```

Here is the full example from their documentation when it comes to mobile web testing on Android:

```
self.desired_capabilities = {}
self.desired_capabilities['platformName'] = 'android'
self.desired_capabilities['platformVersion'] = '4.4'
self.desired_capabilities['browserName'] = 'browser'
self.desired_capabilities['deviceName'] = 'Android' 
self.desired_capabilities['appiumVersion'] = '1.2.2'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two sets of desired capabilities here that are applicable depending on whether you are using Selenium or Appium to run your mobile web tests.

Selenium:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.android();
caps.setCapability("platform", "Linux");
caps.setCapability("version", "4.4");
caps.setCapability("deviceName","Android Emulator");
caps.setCapability("deviceType","phone");
caps.setCapability("deviceOrientation", "portrait");
```

Appium:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.android();
caps.setCapability("appiumVersion", "1.5.0");
caps.setCapability("deviceName","Android Emulator");
caps.setCapability("deviceType","phone");
caps.setCapability("deviceOrientation", "portrait");
caps.setCapability("browserName", "Browser");
caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4");
caps.setCapability("platformName","Android");
```

Both of these configurations will successfully connect to Sauce Labs.

Source:

https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Platform+Configurator#/